# Is it possible to write code for gnome and then build it to windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, ubuntu, gnome, compatibility

I want to write a database program and have it built for a windows machine at work. Is that possible to do without much grinding? (so to speak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. [There's a project to bring GTK+ to windows.](http://sourceforge.net/userapps/mediawiki/alex-sh/index.php?title=Main_Page)

> You may need this installer if you happen to run a GTK+-based
> application and need GTK+ runtime environment to run it. Note that
> this installer does not include any development libraries or headers.
> If you want to develop/compile GTK+ applications for Win32, download
> the dev packages from Tor Lillqvist's pages (see the Links section).

Note, however, that user experience usually deteriorates, the more cross-platform you are.

Comment: I'm using c++ and Qt, Qt looks pretty cross platform but i'm unsure.

Comment: Yea, the Qt website has the words cross-latform in the window title. http://qt.nokia.com/products/

Answer (score 1):

Use a cross-platform language like:

1. Python
2. Java
3. .Net (Mono)

Or, if you prefer C++, use the Boost libraries: http://www.boost.org/

From the website:

> Boost works on almost any modern operating system, including UNIX and
>   Windows variants. Follow the Getting Started Guide to download and
>   install Boost. Popular Linux and Unix distributions such as Fedora,
>   Debian, and NetBSD include pre-built Boost packages. Boost may also
>   already be available on your organization's internal web server.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to SimpleCoder's remarks: If it is a program with an UI, make sure that you use an UI toolkit that also is cross-platform or design it in a way that you can use different UI toolkits with the same business layer (a good pattern would be the [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller)).